# I want to upload product with form to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

````
@extends('master') @section("content") <h1>Upload</h1> <form action="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="price" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price">
        </div>
        <label>Category</label>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Choose
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item</a>
              <br><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diamond</a>
              <br><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Akun</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        <input type="file" name="file"><br><br></div>
        <div>
        <button type="submit"> Sell Item</button>
        </div> </form> @endsection ```
````

````
function upload(Request $req)
{
    
    $products = new Product;
    $products->name=$req->name;
    $products->price=$req->price;
    $products = $req->file('file')->store('Products');
    $req->product()->upload([
        'file'=> $products
    ]);
    return redirect ('/');

} ```
````

i cannot upload it to database. its says

> BadMethodCallException
> Method Illuminate\Http\Request::product does not exist.

i want upload from form to database. before im using product database with seeder

Comment: Change the $req to $request and then check.

Comment: but i did this function upload(Request $req)

Comment: No Stack Overflow question needs to start with "hello"; and "anyone can help me" is an unnecessary invitation.

Comment: You don't "upload" to the database, but save to the database `$product->save()`. I would advise you to read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

**Update your controller upload() function:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function upload(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
         'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt,,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048'
    ]);
    $products = new Product;
    $products->name = $request->name;
    $products->price = $request->price;

    if ($request->file('file')) {
        $fileName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();
        $request->file->move(public_path('/upload'), $fileName);
        $products->file= $filename;
    } 

    $products->save(); 
    return redirect('/');
}
```

> In this public_path('/upload') path you can use your own path where you want to upload your file.

You must have to write this line after your insert query `$products->save();` this line otherwise it could not be store on database. And also you write your file upload path `$file->move('uploads/', $filename);` where your file will be uploaded, you could't define. Your file upload path will be like this `file->move(public_path('/your file path'), $fileName);`

Now, That should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your view

```
<form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="price" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price">
    </div>
    <label>Category</label>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Choose
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item</a>
          <br><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diamond</a>
          <br><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Akun</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br></div>
    <div>
    <button type="submit"> Sell Item</button>
    </div>
   </form>
```

Your Controller

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
$products = new Product;
$products->name = $request->name;
$products->price = $request->price;
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('uploads/', $filename);
        $products->file= $filename;
    }
$products->save();
return redirect('/');
```

}

That should work man

Answer (score 0):

Update your code in controller

> use Illuminate\Http\Request;

```
public function upload(Request $request){
    $products = new Product;
    $products->name = $request->name;
    $products->price = $request->price;

    if ($request->file('file')) {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $path = public_path() . '/uploads';
        $filename = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        if ($file->move($path, $filename)) {
            $products->file= $filename;
        } 
    } 

    $products->save(); 
    return redirect('/');
}
```

In the path section you can define your file path, Where you want to upload your file